# Are all those autoremove s equivalent?

Tags: apt

Suppose I want to autoremove `packageA` in terminal.

I can do

```
sudo apt-get remove packageA 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

---

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove packageA
```

---

```
sudo apt-get autoremove packageA
```

I always use the first way. But I want to know: are all those 3 ways equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all three ways are doing the same thing, but in different. They will all have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

according to apt-get Manual

```
autoremove
       autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
       installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no
       longer needed.
--auto-remove
       If the command is either install or remove, then this option acts
       like running the autoremove command, removing unused dependency
       packages. Configuration Item: APT::Get::AutomaticRemove.
```

`autoremove` is general command that used for  remove dependencies packages that are no longer needed .
if you run command bellow then it will remove `packageA` and its dependencies

```
sudo apt-get autoremove packageA
```

but if you run command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then it will only remove dependencies

and if you run command

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove packageA
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --auto-remove packageA
```

then it will show all `Suggested packages` , `Recommended packages` and packages that need to `upgraded`  and packages that will  remove  for packageA and system . 
if  you want to install `Suggested packages` or `Recommended packages` then you can use `--install-suggests` or `--install-recommends` or `--no-install-recommends` etc.